# unable to load configuration from uwsgi

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have below setup in my Python application

server.py

```
from bots.flask_app import app
from bots.flask_app.api import api
from bots.flask_app.public import public
from bots import db

from bots.commons.helpers.flask.json.serializer import make_alternative_encoder

from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension

import logging

import bots.commons.managers.configuration as ConfigurationManager

logger = logging.getLogger()


#######
# Public functions
#######
def setup_db_and_app():
    # Flask application bootstrap
    config = ConfigurationManager.get_flask_rest_config()
    app.config.update(config)
    logger.debug('Flask configuration object: %s', app.config)

    # MongoDB connection initialization
    db.init_app(app)

    # Debug toolbar enabled only if Flask in debug mode
    if ConfigurationManager.get_raw_flask_rest_config()['flask']['debug']:
        DebugToolbarExtension(app)

    # Replace the serializer with the custom one (for ObjectId and DateTime serialization)
    app.json_encoder = make_alternative_encoder(app.json_encoder)

    # Register the components
    app.register_blueprint(api)
    app.register_blueprint(public)


def start_server():
    setup_db_and_app()
    logger.debug('Registered routes: %s', app.url_map)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

main.py

```
import bots.flask_app.server as FlaskApp

import bots.commons.managers.log as LogManager

# Logging initialization
LogManager.init_logging()

# Defined in server.py
FlaskApp.start_server()
```

I am trying to see whether this applicator can bed served by uwsgi as below

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8080 --protocol=http -w main
```

The output is as follows

```
INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:werkzeug: * Restarting with stat
unable to load configuration from uwsgi
```

My questions
1. Where can I find the configurations which are causing this issue?
2. Can main.py be defined as a callable and used as a parameter for -w?

This is an app which is already written by someone and I am trying make this application served through uwsgi.

Any suggestions would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

I had the 'unable to load configuration from uwsgi' error too. According to  [flask uwsgi docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/uwsgi/)：

> Please make sure in advance that any app.run() calls you might have in your application file are inside an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block or moved to a separate file. Just make sure it’s not called because this will always start a local WSGI server which we do not want if we deploy that application to uWSGI.

I move `app.run()` to `if __name__ == '__main__':`, and the problem solved. Maybe you can try to put `FlaskApp.start_server()` under `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: You save my day!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, I've encountered this error when I forgot to remove `debug=True` from `app.run()`. It makes sense that you can't run the debug server with uwsgi.