# Running Docker image gives: Unable to load configuration from app.py

Tags: python, docker, flask, uwsgi

I am using Docker on a Python Flask webapp, but am getting an error when I try and run it.

```
$ sudo docker run -t imgcomparer6
unable to load configuration from app.py
```

**Python**

In my app.py file, my only instance of `app.run()` in the webapp is within the 
 `'__main__':` function (seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615743/unable-to-load-configuration-from-uwsgi))

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=int("8000"), debug=True)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

#Update OS
RUN sed -i 's/# \(.*multiverse$\)/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

# Install Python
RUN apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip


RUN mkdir /webapp/

# Add requirements.txt
ADD requirements.txt /webapp/
ADD requirements.txt .

# Install uwsgi Python web server
RUN pip install uwsgi

# Install app requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


# Create app directory
ADD . /webapp/

# Set the default directory for our environment
ENV HOME /webapp/
WORKDIR /webapp/

# Expose port 8000 for uwsgi
EXPOSE 8000


ENTRYPOINT ["uwsgi", "--http", "127.0.0.1:8000", "--module", "app:app", "--processes", "1", "--threads", "8"]
#ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

**Directory Structure**

```
app.py
image_data.db
README.txt
requirements.txt
Dockerfile
templates
 - index.html
static/
 - image.js
 - main.css
 img/
   - camera.png
 images/
   - empty
```

EDIT:

Docker images

```
castro@Ezri:~/Desktop/brian_castro_programming_test$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
imgcomparer6        latest              d2af1b18ec87        59 minutes ago      430 MB
imgcomparer5        latest              305fa5062b41        About an hour ago   430 MB
<none>              <none>              e982e54b011a        About an hour ago   430 MB
imgcomparer2        latest              c7e3ad57be55        About an hour ago   430 MB
imgcomparer         latest              a1402ec1efb1        About an hour ago   430 MB
<none>              <none>              8f5126108354        14 hours ago        425 MB
flask-sample-one    latest              9bdc51fa4d7c        23 hours ago        453 MB
ubuntu              latest              6a2f32de169d        12 days ago         117 MB
```

Image Log (gives error)

```
sudo docker logs imgcomparer6
Error: No such container: imgcomparer6
```

Tried running this, as suggested below:

'$ sudo docker run -t imgcomparer6 ; sudo docker logs $(docker ps -lq)'

```
unable to load configuration from app.py
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.27/containers/json?limit=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
"docker logs" requires exactly 1 argument(s).
See 'docker logs --help'.

Usage:  docker logs [OPTIONS] CONTAINER

Fetch the logs of a container
```

ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
e80bfd0a3a11        imgcomparer6        "uwsgi --http 127...."   54 minutes ago      Exited (1) 54 minutes ago                       musing_fermat
29c188ede9ba        imgcomparer6        "uwsgi --http 127...."   54 minutes ago      Exited (1) 54 minutes ago                       kind_jepsen
a58945d9cd86        imgcomparer6        "uwsgi --http 127...."   55 minutes ago      Exited (1) 55 minutes ago                       musing_wright
ca70b624df5e        imgcomparer6        "uwsgi --http 127...."   55 minutes ago      Exited (1) 55 minutes ago                       brave_hugle
964a1366b105        imgcomparer6        "uwsgi --http 127...."   55 minutes ago      Exited (1) 55 minutes ago                       clever_almeida
155c296a3dce        imgcomparer6        "uwsgi --http 127...."   2 hours ago         Exited (1) 2 hours ago                          jovial_heisenberg
0a6a3bb55b55        imgcomparer5        "uwsgi --http 127...."   2 hours ago         Exited (1) 2 hours ago                          sharp_mclean
76d4f40c4b82        e982e54b011a        "uwsgi --http 127...."   2 hours ago         Exited (1) 2 hours ago                          kind_hodgkin
918954bf416a        d73c44a6c215        "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir..."   2 hours ago         Exited (1) 2 hours ago                          amazing_bassi
205276ba1ab2        d73c44a6c215        "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir..."   2 hours ago         Exited (1) 2 hours ago                          distracted_joliot
86a180f071c6        d73c44a6c215        "/bin/sh -c '#(nop..."   2 hours ago         Created                                         goofy_torvalds
fc1ec345c236        imgcomparer2        "uwsgi --http 127...."   2 hours ago         Created                                         wizardly_boyd
b051d4cdf0c6        imgcomparer         "uwsgi --http 127...."   2 hours ago         Created                                         jovial_mclean
ed78e965755c        d73c44a6c215        "/bin/sh -c '#(nop..."   3 hours ago         Created                                         elated_shirley
a65978d30c8f        d73c44a6c215        "/bin/sh -c '#(nop..."   3 hours ago         Created                                         vigilant_wright
760ac5a0281b        d73c44a6c215        "/bin/sh -c '#(nop..."   3 hours ago         Created                                         xenodochial_heyrovsky
9d7d8bcb2226        d73c44a6c215        "/bin/sh -c '#(nop..."   3 hours ago         Created                                         sleepy_noyce
36012d4c6115        d73c44a6c215        "/bin/sh -c '#(nop..."   3 hours ago         Created                                         adoring_hypatia
deacab89f416        d73c44a6c215        "/bin/sh -c '#(nop..."   3 hours ago         Created                                         objective_franklin
43e894f8fb9c        d73c44a6c215        "/bin/sh -c '#(nop..."   3 hours ago         Created                                         sleepy_hodgkin
2d190d0fc6e5        d73c44a6c215        "/bin/sh -c '#(nop..."   3 hours ago         Created                                         modest_hoover
b1640a039c31        d73c44a6c215        "/bin/sh -c '#(nop..."   3 hours ago         Created                                         affectionate_galileo
baf94cf2dc6e        d73c44a6c215        "/bin/sh -c '#(nop..."   3 hours ago         Created                                         affectionate_elion
2b54996907b6        d73c44a6c215        "/bin/sh -c '#(nop..."   3 hours ago         Created                                         elastic_wiles
663d4e096938        8f5126108354        "/bin/sh -c 'pip i..."   15 hours ago        Exited (1) 15 hours ago                         admiring_agnesi
```

Comment: post `docker logs your_container` and also `docker events `when you launch it This is not your problem, but you hsould group your RUN, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: You need to do `docker ps` for running containers.

Comment: post `sudo docker run -t imgcomparer6 ; docker logs $(docker ps -lq)`

Comment: I think that's an invalid command, `docker logs takes exactly 1 argument` see my edit.

Comment: Your container dies too quickly, what says `docker events`? Post `docker ps -a` it should show

Comment: I don't get any results from docker events, not sure how to get the options to work. But I posted docker ps -a

Comment: launch a container with a shell and start checking `sudo docker run -it imgcomparer6 bash`

Comment: `sudo docker run -it imgcomparer6 bash` just gives an err msg: 
`unable to load configuration from bash`

Comment: When you have both a ENTRYPOINT and CMD, Docker will combine them.  `uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:8000 --module app:app --processes 1 --threads 8 app.py`. I think the problem is that you are passing `app.py` as a uwsgi config file, instead of a python script. Try `--wsgi-file app.py` instead.

Comment: This is why you get the error when you try to run bash, as well. You are still using the ENTRYPOINT, which means uwsgi will look for a config file named `bash`. You can override entrypoint by using `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash imgcomparer6`

Answer (score 0):

Here are two quick fixes for **app.py** and the **Dockerfile** and it should run.

Change any `127.0.0.1` references to `0.0.0.0`. Docker binds ports on `0.0.0.0`.

```
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int("8000"), debug=True)
```

For the Dockerfile you can use `CMD` and/or `ENTRYPOINT` to run commands when the container starts, but in this case you don't need both. This will work:

```
CMD exec uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:8000 --module app:app --processes 1 --threads 8
```

Then:

```
docker build .
docker run -p 8000:8000 <image>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with how you invoke uwsgi. The way you are passing `app.py` tells uwsgi that it's a config file, not a python callable.

I prefer to use a ini file to configure uwsgi, since it's cleaner than adding a bunch of command line options to the Dockerfile. See the relevant docs for how to deploy flask and uwsgi if you face problems.

[Uwsgi: Quickstart Flask](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html?#deploying-flask)

Here's a sample uwsgi.ini and Dockerfile config. It's based on the example in uwsgi's docs, using `wsgi-file` and `callable` parameters to start the flask wsgi function. This should work the same whether you are running inside docker or not.

(This means that there's should be no use for the `if __name__` block in app.py)

uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 0.0.0.0:8000
chdir = /webapp/
wsgi-file = app.py
callable = app
...
```

Dockerfile:

```
... 
# no ENTRYPOINT, use only CMD
CMD ["uwsgi", "/webapp/uwsgi.ini"]
```

Avoid using both ENTRYPOINT and CMD, until you understand exactly [how they interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact). If in doubt, just use CMD.